# Using wizards with project templates in VS 2019 : Wizard is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wizard, vsix, project-template

I'm trying to create a wizard for my project template by referring to this article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2019

I have done all the steps as in the documentation. But when I try to create a new project it doesn't show the form and it didn't use the updated version of the project template.

It gives following error.

[image]

`RunStarted` method looks like following:

```
public void RunStarted(object automationObject,
            Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary,
            WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
        {
            try
            {
                // Display a form to the user. The form collects
                // input for the custom message.
                inputForm = new UserInputForm();
                inputForm.ShowDialog();

                customMessage = UserInputForm.CustomMessage;

                // Add custom parameters.
                replacementsDictionary.Add("$custommessage$",
                    customMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

You can check the full code here - https://github.com/kalpanibhagya/ProjectTemplateRacr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with the namespace in `WizardImplementation.cs` class in VSIX project. It was `MyProjectWizard` But it should be `WizardRacr`.

Comment: Hi, @Kalpani Ranasinghe. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.

Comment: @HuiLiu-MFST Yes, it solved the problem! Thanks for letting me know :)